# Hello World doesn't work on JSBin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsbin

What's wrong with my simple hello world attempt? Here's [the JSBin](https://jsbin.com/lopajimiqo/edit?html,js,output)

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <h1>Hello {this.props.name}</h1>
    )
  }
}

React.render(
  <Hello name="World!"/>,
  document.getElementById('name');
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a very recent change introduced with 0.14. They split up React into a core library and the DOM adapter. Rendering is now done via `ReactDOM.render()`

Since you are using version 15.1.0 you should use ReactDOM.render() and in order to do so you need to include react-dom as a dependency in your jsbin html as

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Also in `ReactDOM.render` you need to place the semicolon after 
`ReactDOM.render();` and not inside it.

Here is the working snippet.

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
     <h1>Hello {this.props.name}</h1>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <Hello name="World!"/>,
  document.getElementById('name')
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script> 
  <div id="name"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You render to the DOM with the module `ReactDOM`, separate from `React`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Hello name="World!" />, document.getElementById("name"));
```

Also, your semicolon was misplaced. Remember, `ReactDOM` is a different module. Per [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html):

> The react-dom package provides DOM-specific methods that can be used at the top level of your app...
>
> ---
>
> **ReactDOM.render**
>
> ```
> render(
>   ReactElement element,
>   DOMElement container,
>   [function callback]
> )
> ```